# confusing statement in shell script

Tags: bash, shell, unix

```
while sizes=`sizes $pgid`
do
    set -- $sizes
    sample=$((${@/#/+}))
    let peak="sample > peak ? sample : peak"
    sleep 0.1
done
```

i am confused about the below statement:

```
sample=$((${@/#/+}))
```

could anybody explain this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The '`${@/#/+}`' part is a regular expression expansion:

> ```
> ${parameter/pattern/string}
> ```
>
> The pattern is expanded to produce a pattern just as in filename expansion.
>   Parameter is expanded and the longest match of pattern against its value is
>   replaced with string. If pattern begins with '`/`', all matches of pattern are replaced
>   with string. Normally only the first match is replaced. If pattern begins
>   with '`#`', it must match at the beginning of the expanded value of parameter.
>   If pattern begins with '`%`', it must match at the end of the expanded value of
>   parameter. If string is null, matches of pattern are deleted and the / following
>   pattern may be omitted. If parameter is '`@`' or '`*`', the substitution operation
>   is applied to each positional parameter in turn, and the expansion is the resultant
>   list. If parameter is an array variable subscripted with '`@`' or '`*`', the
>   substitution operation is applied to each member of the array in turn, and the
>   expansion is the resultant list.

So, it looks like it replaces the empty string at the start of each value in the argument list '`$@`' with a '`+`'.  It's key merit is that it prefixes each argument in one fell swoop; otherwise, it is similar to `"+$var"`.

---

The '`$(( ... ))` part is an arithmetic expression.  It performs arithmetic on the expression between the parentheses.  So, in context, it adds up the values in the argument list, assuming they are all numeric.  Given the expansion, it might yield:

```
set -- 2 3 5 7 11
sample=$((${@/#/+}))
sample1=$((+2 +3 +5 +7 +11))
echo $sample = $sample1
```

and hence '`28 = 28`'.

Answer (score 3):

Let's take the line from the inside out.

```
${@/#/+}
```

This is a parameter expansion, which expands the `$@` parameter (which in this case, will be an array of all of the items in `$sizes`), and then does a pattern match on each item, replacing each matched sequence with `+`. The `#` in the pattern matches the beginning of each item in the input; it doesn't actually consume anything, so the replacement by `+` will just add a `+` before each item. You can see this in action with a simple test function:

```
$ function tst() { echo ${@/#/+}; }
$ tst 1 2 3
+1 +2 +3
```

The result of this is then substituted into `$(( ))`, which performs arithmetic expansion, evaluating the expression within it. The end result is that the variable `$sample` is set to the sum of all of the numbers in `$sizes`.

Answer (score 1):

It's an arithmetic expansion of a string replacement.

`$(( ))` is arithmetic expansion - eg `echo $((1 + 2))`.
`${var/x/y}` is a string replacement; in this case, replace the first `#` in a line with `+`. `$@` is a variable that in this case contains $sizes; this will replace the string and then looks like it will add the values in it.

Comment: Nope, it won't replace the first `#` with a `+`, `#` in the pattern a `${var/pat/string}` replacement will match the beginning of each item in `var`, so it will add an `+` to the beginning of element in `$@`.

Answer (score 1):

${var/old/new} expands $var, changing any "old" to "new".
${var/#old/new} insists that the match start at the start of the value
${var/#/new} substitutes at the start of every variable
${@/#/new} (and $@) applies to each parameter

$(( 1 + 3 )) replaces with the arithmetic result.

```
$(( ${@/#/+/ ))
```

Expands $@, the arguments from set -- $sizes, prepends a "+" to each parameter and runs the result through an arithmetic evaluation. It looks like it is adding all values on each line.